# No Android Studio como visualizar o que sai fora da tela?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Estou utilizando texto  e uma imagem com isso eles sai fora da tela mas com `ScrollView` é possivel vela mas na Android Studio na telinha fica o celular para acompanhar o design o que sai tela você não a vê, gostaria de puxar a tela para cima do Android Studio para poder observar  e colocar alguns botões

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Texto"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/f1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/f1" />
            </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Não entendi, você quer alterar o layout de exibição do android studio, não da sua aplicação?

Comment: @sim eu queria visualizar fora do limite da tela do `Android Studio`

Comment: @DiegoFelipe sim

Comment: Eu tambem sempre tive essa duvida, eu tinha criado um app de piano dai as teclas ficam fora da tela, eu reduzia o zoom no android studio, mas nao sei se tem outra forma de visualizar os itens fora da tela. Tambem ja vi pessoas que criam um novo dispositivo virtual com tela de uns 800x4000 so pra usar na previsualização. Só vi metodos de gambiarra mesmo kkkk

Comment: Bem que alguém poderia ensinar a fazer essa gambiarra ou melhor artifício técnico KKKKKK